# Binding to method<T> with ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

We are defining implementations to our services in an external xml configuration file. We have the name of the service, the class to instantiate, the assembly containing the class. We are migrating from an Spring AOP code.

For simple services it works without an itch  with `kernel.Bind().To()`. 
We load the assembly, create an instance, return it to `To()`.

However some services inherit from another class like :

```
  internal abstract Bar<T>: EntityBo<T> where T : IAddress
  {
     protected Bar(IAddress adr)
     {
     }
  }

  internal Foo:Bar<ILocalAddress>, ILocalAddressService {
  }
```

When I try to get ILocalAddressService from the Kernel, I get a Ninject.ActivationException :

> Error activating ILocalAddress No matching bindings are available, and
>   the type is not self-bindable. 
>   Activation path:
>   2) Injection of dependency ILocalAddress into parameter adr of constructor of type Foo
>   1) Request for ILocalAddressService

**The Kernel is in a different project and doesn't know about the interface or its implementation.**

How can I make it work ?

Comment: Need a service area that you have registered.

Comment: Would you have an example or a reference ?

Comment: i dont know if its the same problem but i use IResolutionRoot to add other dependencies at runtime in  kernel see the part of secondview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236654/factory-ninject-extension-instead-iresolutionroot-caliburn    in fact i inject IResolutionroot to access to the kernel